# Knockout.js with google maps API, filtering markers

Tags: google-maps, knockout.js

```
   function MapsApi(){

    var self= this;
    self.marker=[];
    self.map="";
    self.latLangArr= ko.observableArray([{name:'Windsor Sculpture Park',isFiltered: ko.observable(true),marker:{lat: 42.314831, lng: -83.060117},contentString:'Windsor Sculpture Park'},
        {name:'Ambassador Bridge',isFiltered: ko.observable(true),marker:{lat: 42.312, lng: -83.074},contentString:'Ambassador Bridge'},
        {name:'Detroit River',isFiltered: ko.observable(true),marker:{lat: 42.300, lng: -83.090},contentString:'Detroit River'},
        {name:'The Manchester',isFiltered: ko.observable(true),marker:{lat: 42.31480, lng: -83.03682},contentString:'The Manchester'},
        {name:'Caesars Windsor',isFiltered: ko.observable(true),marker:{lat: 42.320375, lng: -83.033764},contentString:'Caesars Windsor'}]);
    self.Query = ko.observable('');
    self.searchResults = ko.computed(function(){
       var q = self.Query();
        return self.latLangArr().filter(function(i) {
              var listFilter =  i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) >= 0;
              return listFilter;



        });



    });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', self.initialize.bind(self));
}
```

//this helps me with filtering the list but not the corresponding markers on the google map.

I want to filter the markers as well.
here is some of the html code:

```
    <div style="margin: 10px">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
        <input type="text"  data-bind="value: Query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" class="form-control" placeholder="search place" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">

    </div>
      <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach:searchResults">
    <li class="list-group-item" data-bind="click:$root.getMarker.bind($root),text: name"></li>

</ul></div></div>
<div class="col-md-8"> <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: you need to show the code on how are you are initializing google map and adding markers to google map with knockout. Basically, you need to redraw the map with filtered markers.

Comment: If what you have currently successfully filters the list you can use the 'setVisible()' method with true and false to make the marker show or hide.